# Error: spawn ENOENT in server application

Tags: node.js, express, render.com

I'm using apng2gif to convert a file in my render.com server, but everytime it gets called, it returns that error. Though it works just fine in the localhost.

```
await apng2gif(filePath, gifPath)
```

The full error is:

```
Error: spawn /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/.pnpm/apng2gif-bin@1.7.1/node_modules/apng2gif-bin/bin/linux/apng2gif ENOENT
```

I've seen some solutions but they don't work in my case since I have no control over the spawn. I'm using the same node version for both locally and in my server.

Comment: Can you try `npm install` and run the application. Just to confirm it has nothing to do with `pnpm`.

Comment: @SagarDevkota I did it and even changed pnpm-lock.yaml to package-lock.json but I still get the same error